# "the probability of" vs "a/an +adjective +probability"

Tags: determiners

when should we use "a/an" before the word and when should we use "the" because for example, we use:

> 1 there's a high probability
> not there is the high probability

but we do say

> 2 there's the probability of 95% that tomorrow it will rain.

Comment: Do we? I would say "there's a 95% probability that...".

Comment: 2 is not idiomatic with 'the', unless it somehow refers to something already mentioned.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: In a knee-jerk reaction I upvoted your comment, then realised I don't agree. ***The** probability of rain tomorrow is 95%*, and in principle I could even *start* a conversation with that, so it's obviously not "somehow referring to something already mentioned".

Comment: In a closely-related context, *A lot of things can happen in a year. The king might die. The horse might die. I might die. And, who knows? There's always **a/the chance** the horse will sing*. I'm happy with either article there, even if *neither* are actually used in the link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My comment was knee-jerk too. Using "the" has to refer to something that exists, but the probability of rain tomorrow must exist, whatever its level. The particular form of "There's the probability..." would, I think, have to refer to something that was already mentioned or implied.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: I like your way of phrasing the analysis - *the probability of rain tomorrow must exist, whatever its level*. How come in all the philosopjhical musings I've read over the years, no-one has ever pointed out that *the probability of God existing must exist, whatever its level*. That argument "in favour" of theism seems to me at least as inarguable as [Pascal's Wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_wager) (no matter *how* low the probability, it can't be zero, so given the infinitely disastrous consequences of getting it wrong, we should just shut up and go to church).

Comment: @FumbleFingers On this I don't agree. When I say "whatever its level", I am including zero in that range. When the probability of rain is zero, I don't carry an umbrella.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Given that serious cosmologists seriously entertain the idea of [Boltzmann Brains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain), I'm tempted to suggest there's not really a "zero probability" of *anything*. Even if I could thoroughly check out the Moon to establish for sure that it *wasn't* made of green cheese, a hypothetically non-existent wizard or God could have turned it into said green cheese immediately after I turned my back! More specifically, I could refute Pascal by simply pointing out that imho there's ***zero***  chance of his wager paying off (so don't bet! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think lunar green cheese is probably the right comparison for the likelihood of any deity-centered creation myth to be true. Thinking back on the difference between the use of "the probability" and "a probability"..."the probability" exists because one can analyze the probability of anything, and it can be close to or at zero. But saying "there is a probability" suggests something more than zero.